# Adding a new cassandra node fails

Tags: cassandra

I try to add a new cassandra node to an existing cluster.
IP address:

- 172.31.37.163/32, Port 9160 --> DB Instance 1, seed 1 (already in use with data and cassandra 2 binding)
- 172.31.39.184 --> DB Instance 2 (already in use with data and cassandra 2 binding)
- 172.31.44.13 --> DB Instance 3 (new node)

These are the steps that I took:

1. Stop DB Instance 2, only DB Instance 1 (seed 1) is running --> what
   are here the right sequence? can I start also DB Instance 2, during
   adding the new node?
2. cassandra 2.0.17 on new AWS instance installed
3. stop cassandra service
4. set up `cassandra.yaml` as follows:

   ```
   cluster_name: 'Test Cluster' (on all nodes the same name)  
   num_tokens: 256        
   class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
   parameters: 
   seeds: "172.31.37.163"        
   listen_address:        
   rpc_address: 0.0.0.0        
   endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
   ```
5. Start cassandra service
6. reboot AWS DB Instance
7. with notetool status on the new node I receive:

   ```
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-13:~$ nodetool status
   Datacenter: DC1

   Status=Up/Down
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
   -- Address Load Tokens Owns (effective) Host ID Rack
   UN 172.31.44.13 143.08 KB 256 100.0% 701760b7-dd09-4669-a65f-86ebb7da529f RAC1
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-13:~$
   ```

   …instead of (seed 1):

   ```
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-163:~$ nodetool status
   Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
   Datacenter: DC1

   Status=Up/Down
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
   -- Address Load Tokens Owns Host ID Rack
   UN 172.31.37.163 3.88 GB 256 52.0% 28da1a11-d063-4acd-8a63-d87c3b7fa980 RAC1
   DN 172.31.39.184 ? 256 48.0% 0c206719-5642-4f98-87d4-39b750202b9c r1
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-163:~$
   ```

Why I could not see the the ip address from seed 1?

Comment: Did you changed `cassandra-rackdc.properties`  file

Comment: yes, all nodes are configured as follows: dc=DC1
rack=RAC1